# How to create arrays without describe the structure?

Tags: arrays

I try to field the result of an http request into an array but I've some difficulties. I get data to create a menu relating to the previous menu item choose. So for this menu chosen I get all sub menu. These sub menu have properties like `id_menu` (relating to menu chosen) id_parent (to know if they are sub menu of sub menu) and other like name... So when I get all these sub menu I want to store them into an array. I want to have all sub without parent in the first line then all the sub sub menu Under their parent sub menu.

When I get data, I loop on them to see if some have no `id_parent` then I push them into an array I've named `tabRes = [];` In the same loop I recheck now if they've id_parent then I try to loop on tabRes to check which one (id of sub menu) match the id_parent (of the others sub menu). Then I want to create an attribute (child) of type table on this element to add an array where I will store sub sub menu.

```js
this.sousMenuService
    .getAllByMenu(this.message.id)
    .subscribe( sousMenu => {
                        this.sousMenus = sousMenu;

                        for (let x of this.sousMenus) {
                            if (x.id_parent == null) {
                                console.log(x.nom);
                                this.tabRes.push(x);
                            }

                            if (x.id_parent != null) {
                                for (let y of this.tabRes) {
                                    if (x.id_parent == y.id) {
                                        y.child.push(x);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        console.log(this.tabRes[0].child);
                });
```

I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

I may be going by the wrong method. I want to create a table like [{element1id:1,....,child:[{element2id_parent:1...}]},{element2id:2,....,child:[{element2id_parent:2...}]}]

Comment: child appears to be a property of y that you are creating on the fly. If so, its default value is 'undefined' and you have to assign an empty array to it and then push to the array. If this is what you are interested in, let me know and I'll make it an answer with some more detail.

Comment: child is supposed to be an element of elements of tabRes ( the ony one I've declared at the top of my file (tabRes=[])). And y is supposed to be an element Inside tabRes. and yes I want to add child property to y. I Don't see how to assign this array :/ Thank you for your time Alireza .
maybe after pushing x into tabRes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're defining a property on the fly, it'll be `undefined`. You can assign anything you want to it, but you can't *expect* it to be an array and use the `push` method on it.

The solution is to check it for a *falsy* value (`undefined`) here and if it's `false` assign to it a new array with your desired value as an element of it. If it isn't `false`, you are sure that an array has been already assigned to it, so you can push new elements on top of that array.

```js
     this.sousMenuService.getAllByMenu(this.message.id).subscribe( sousMenu => {
                        this.sousMenus = sousMenu;
                        for (let x of this.sousMenus) {
                                if(x.id_parent == null){
                                        console.log(x.nom);
                                        this.tabRes.push(x);
                                }
                                if (x.id_parent != null){
                                        for (let y of this.tabRes){
                                                if (x.id_parent == y.id){
                                                        if(!y.child)
                                                            child = [x];
                                                        else
                                                            y.child.push(x);
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        console.log(this.tabRes[0].child);
                });
```